# Problems with Hashing (with BinaryFormatter) with class object containing negative number

Tags: c#, .net, hash

Basically, we have a number of POCO's which we convert to hash values. The purpose is to use the hash string as the unique identifer for that particular object. If we find another object with the same values, the hash string should is the same, etc.

However, we have come across a problem where the hash results appears to be the same if the integer field contains a negative number.

Below is our extension method to Serialize and hash the given object: -

```
public static string Serialize<T>(this T classObject) where T : class
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, classObject);

            stream.Position = 0;
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();

            return text;
        }
    }

public static string ToHash(this string str)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

        var md5 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    }
```

In order to demonstrate this problem, I have created a sample class: -

```
[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    public string StringA;
    public string StringB;
    public int? Created;
}
```

Here is my test code...

```
        var testZero = new TestClass
            {
                StringA = "String A",
                StringB = "String B",
                Created = 0,
            };
        var testNull = new TestClass
            {
                StringA = "String A",
                StringB = "String B",
                Created = null,
            };
        var testMinusOne = new TestClass
            {
                StringA = "String A",
                StringB = "String B",
                Created = -1

            };
        var testMinusTwo = new TestClass
            {
                StringA = "String A",
                StringB = "String B",
                Created = -2
            };
        var testMinusThree = new TestClass
            {
                StringA = "String A",
                StringB = "String B",
                Created = -3
            };
        var testMinusOneHundred = new TestClass
            {
                StringA = "String A",
                StringB = "String B",
                Created = -100
            };
        var testOneHundred = new TestClass
            {
                StringA = "String A",
                StringB = "String B",
                Created = 100
            };

        var rHashZero = testZero.Serialize().ToHash();
        var rHashNull = testNull.Serialize().ToHash();
        var rHashMinusOne = testMinusOne.Serialize().ToHash();
        var rHashMinusTwo = testMinusTwo.Serialize().ToHash();
        var rHashMinusThree = testMinusThree.Serialize().ToHash();
        var rHashMinusHundred = testMinusOneHundred.Serialize().ToHash();
        var rHashHundred = testOneHundred.Serialize().ToHash();
```

The variables (at the end) contain the following values :-

```
        rHashZero = "aFJROVaqEbWneZJkDnB00qkxPf4TF/w+22VhgR+4nHU=";
        rHashNull = "0/tsIhQzZK+Jirnee1o8QTjU8G1hOB/ODdnr2UipBPU=";
        rHashMinusOne = "Q5xsfYpm/Em2vw19N9283Gq9fUoI7WxN+ip61S/m3h0=";
        rHashMinusTwo = "Q5xsfYpm/Em2vw19N9283Gq9fUoI7WxN+ip61S/m3h0=";
        rHashMinusThree = "Q5xsfYpm/Em2vw19N9283Gq9fUoI7WxN+ip61S/m3h0=";
        rHashMinusHundred = "Q5xsfYpm/Em2vw19N9283Gq9fUoI7WxN+ip61S/m3h0=";
        rHashHundred = "3q6S9vZPujnSc5b2YAbtD61Dj+4B5ZzoILnL1lH291M=";
```

My main question is why are the objects with the negative integer value all return the same hash string? Despite StringA and StringB being the same, the Created field is not the same.

If anyone can explain this to me - that would be great. Also, Is there a solution?
I have also tested this by removing the nullable (?) from the int, but the results are the same.

PS -- I am convinced I came across a site which mentioned something about negative numbers, but was convinced it was 'fixed' in a later .net release. This is going back a while now so that site may no longer exist.

I tried to find info about this on the internet but no luck. Maybe I am not using correct words on a search engine?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you reading the result of `BinaryFormatter` *as a string*? It's not a string, and it's pretty much guaranteed it's not properly encoded UTF-16.

Comment: Try `return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());`

Comment: Why does your hash function return a string?

Comment: Why not just overide GetHashCode and create a hash based on the property values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading the result of result of the `BinaryFormatter` as if it were a properly formed UTF-16 string. It is not.

Unicode is not a simple 1:1 mapping between bytes and characters, unlike ASCII. This means that you managed to malform the data. It's obvious when you print out the string that results from the `SerializeMethod`:

For the 100 case, I get

```
□□□□□����□□□□□□□□□□□□□Cquery_rtzxks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null□□□□□□UserQuery+TestClass□□□□□StringA□StringB□Created□□□□System.Int32□□□□□□□□□□String A□□□□□□String B□□d□□□□
```

While for -100, I get

```
□□□□□����□□□□□□□□□□□□□Cquery_rtzxks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null□□□□□□UserQuery+TestClass□□□□□StringA□StringB□Created□□□□System.Int32□□□□□□□□□□String A□□□□□□String B□□����□
```

(the namespaces etc. are from LINQPad. The important point are the *values* like `□����□` right there at the end)

It should be rather obvious that your "conversion" is throwing away tons of data. Due to the way the memory is organized, this makes your code *appear* to work sometimes, but *that* is the exception - it's just that by chance, some values of the serialized integer happen to be proper unicode characters, which would then result in a different string - if they are *not* proper characters, they will be the same.

The solution is simple - don't pretend random byte sequences are valid UTF-16 strings. Just pass the `byte[]` you get from `stream.ToArray()` and be done with it. If you absolutely want `string` for some reason, use `Convert.ToBase64String`.

Also, since this isn't clear in your question, do not treat hashes as unique - they are not. The relation is "if the values are the same, the hashes must be the same", but *not* "if the hashes are the same, the values must be the same". So in a way, your hashing function is just fine, it doesn't violate this relation. It's not all that useful either, though.

So, why is this giving you trouble for negative numbers specially? The short answer is "it doesn't". This has to do with how numbers are saved in `BinaryFormatter` - negative values are really large, for example, -1 would be `0xFFFFFFFF`. Those are turned to `�`, of course, because there's no code-point mappings. On the other hand, the test positive values you've used are relatively small, and have a good chance of hitting ASCII-like code points. For example, the value of 100 is `0x64000000` - and `0x64` is `d`, which is fine. However, for example, 65535 and 65532 will have the same "string" representation, because both `0xFFFF` and `0xFFFC` are incorrect code points, and will be resolved into `�`. When you then feed this to your hashing function, the two input strings will be exactly the same. For negative numbers, -3 and -65532 will produce different hashes, for example.

Comment: Hi Luaan. Thank you for the feedback! I think my problem is I was trying to solve this problem by going the wrong direction. After reviewing I noticed that BinaryFormatter is not used properly. I doubt it will be needed at all. I just assumed (yes, I used assumed here) that the code already in place was essentially correct. I am refactoring this now... and taking your notes on board on top! Once I find out how to mark this answer, I will do so. Thank you!

;-)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everyones answer. I have pretty much gone the direction of using stream.ToArray() and Convert.ToBase64 to return the string. The results look promising at this time.

I apologise that this question is causing lots of "wtf" and I understand the downvote with more likely to follow! I am not a hardcore C# developer and I am working on a large project at this time. I was not suppose to be on this, either! Trying to piece this project together was a bit of a challenge especially when a half-finished change involved negative numbers.

Thanks again.